# google +1 button not working

Tags: javascript, api, debugging, google-apps

I have a very complex site with 11 js files included on each page.

I have recently added the google +1 button, with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>

<g:plusone></g:plusone>
```

This displays the +1 button correctly until I click on it.  When I click it, I get this error: https://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=plusone_button_error&answer=1199142

I have gone through the suggestions, and none are relevant in this case.  I created a test page with only the above code in it and uploaded it to the same server.  The test page works perfectly.

I'm assuming there is a js code conflict somewhere but I don't know how to debug it.  Chrome and IE don't throw up any errors.

Comment: 11 JavaScript files? Hmmm... concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error here. I found that the page is taking too long to load and because of that the button could not work.

I commented some piece of code and page loaded faster than before and the button worked.